# Python - how do I write pattern for nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I struggling with some exercise. I have to create a nested dictionary, and then initiate it. I want (if it's possible) to initiate that dictionary using for loop. The thing is I'm not sure how I should declare some kind of a pattern. I'll try to explain it on some example.

Let's say we have a empty dictionary

```
dictionary = {}
```

I want from it to have specified patter such as

```
dictionary = {Name: {"Surname": surname, "Age": age}
```

the variables such as "name", "surname", "age" will be initiated and added to the dictionary in for loop

```
for x in range(0, 2):

name = input("Enter some name: ")
surname= input("Enter some surname: ")
age = int(input("Enter some shoe age: "))
```

How I may write down some pattern to update things to it later on?

Comment: Why do you do this instead of just building a new dictionary entry for every iteration?

Comment: Set `dictionary = {}`, then in `for` loop `dictionary[name]={"Surname":surname, "Age":age}

Comment: Well, I thought that creating new dict in loop won't  fill all places. I have to add 4 names, and values for them. I'll try that out

Comment: @JasonYang that was it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you:

```
dictionary = {}

for _ in range(3):
    name = input("Enter some name: ")
    surname= input("Enter some surname: ")
    age = int(input("Enter some shoe age: "))
    dictionary[name] = {"Surname": surname, "Age": age}
```